# Can I say "X decreases the contribution of our report"?

Tags: expressions, verbs

I'd like to mention that the contribution of my writing report will be less if I do not describe about previous research.

Is it possible to say that "it decrease the contribution of our report if I do not describe...."? I'm worrying especially about the usage of decrease. Thanks.

Comment: I think that would be very poorly worded.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you. please let us know the better alternative.

Comment: Something along the lines of "In order to appreciate the contribution of this report it is necessary to recap some previous research."  Although I'm not sure that "contribution" is the proper term to use here.  Also, it's common in many reports to have a section, early in the document, labeled "Prior research" or something of that nature.  Depending on the style of the document this may eliminate the need for an introductory sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the choice of verb.

At Google Books:

"reduce the report's [value]"

is a search field already too large to give significant hits. Thus, we remove "value".

"reduce the report's"
About 68 results

"weaken the report's"
About 26 results

"decrease the report's"
8 results

"lessen the report's"
3 results

I'd select "reduce" based on majority rule.

--

Now, your "it" is troublesome, because we don't know what the pronoun would reference.

Thus I'd suggest something like:

*The contribution of my report **would be reduced [considerably]**, **should I** decide not to describe previous research.*

*The contribution of my report **would be reduced [considerably]**, **if I were to** decide not to describe previous research.*

Answer (score 1):

"Contribution" doesn't make much sense to me in this context. Would "value" be better?

"Decrease" is fine. But you could use "reduce" as an equivalent.

So, maybe: "it will decrease the value of our report if I do not describe..."

BTW, in your introductory sentence you say "describe about" - the "about" is unnecessary (ie wrong :))